# Wordpress custom page dynamic call only works on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, simplemodal

I'm using Wordpress with a custom page (ajax-handler) to open every post on a simple modal dialog, but something weird is happening. The code works perfect on my localhost, but when it's at the server, everytime I click on a post to open it the server returns a 404 (Not Found) error.

I followed [this](http://wordpressthemescollection.com/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery-488.html) tutorial and here is my code:

```
$('#content article').on('click', function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('rel');
   $('<div id="popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('<?php echo home_url(); ?>/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({ });
});
```

I already tried changing the path without / before the ? and tried with “.php” at the end of the filename

None of them works like localhost. Any thoughts?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is home_url? Does it print anything? If it does than what?

Comment: is this `var id = $scr(this).attr('rel');` a typo? it will create errors. It should be `$(this).attr('rel');`

Comment: Capri82, home_url variable prints the beginning of my webpage as in echo home_url = 'http://www.mywordpresspage.com/'

Comment: CodeGodie, yes my mistake, this is a typo! In my code it's exactly like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm a little surprised your code worked on localhost. Maybe something to do with your .htaccess.

The standard way to do Ajax in WordPress is to send the request to the standard WP Ajax handler like so:

```
$('#content article').on('click', function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('rel');
   $('<div id="popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load( '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>, {id: id}).modal({ });
});
```

You then add an action to handle the ajax call. If your application is a front-end application, as it appears, then this would be something like:

```
function ajax_handler() {
    if ($_POST['id']) {
        // Probably something like what you already have
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'ajax_handler' );
```